# Массово присвоить записям новые рубрики

Tags: wordpress

**Вводные данные:**

1. 42 000 записей
2. 400 рубрик
3. 200 меток
4. 80 000 рубрик в кастомной таксономии, созданных из пересечения Рубрика + Метка

Подскажите, как массово привязать записи к кастомным рубрикам?

**Например:**

Рубрика Новости, в ней 100 записей

Метка Барселона, в ней 20 записей

Нужно эти 120 записей(записи могут повторяться) привязать к рубрике Новости Барселоны, которая была создана из пересечения Рубрика(Новости) + Метка(Барселона).

Answer (score 1):

> Нужно эти 120 записей(записи могут повторяться) привязать к рубрике
> Новости Барселоны,

Стандартным быстрым редактированием. Предварительно увеличив число отражаемых постов.

[image]

После чего ставшими ненужными рубрики удалить.

Comment: Как вариант, не подумал об этом.

Спасибо

Comment: Присваивать руками 80к комбинаций, такое себе занятие)

Comment: Я ответил именно на то, что ты просил. Ты писал про 120 записей, а не 80к. А для большого кол-ва есть плагины массового редактирования. С которыми ради пары сотен не имеет смысла заморачиваться.

Comment: Так я же привел пример и дал вводные данные что 80к новых рубрик есть, к которым надо посты привязать.

Comment: Я не увидел связи между началом вопроса и самим вопросом. В вопросе ты спрашивал про 120 постов.  На это и был ответ. Но 80к РУБРИК? Ты явно что-то не то сделал. Даже 400 это дофига Разве что для ГСа  "нормально".